# DataGrid ScrollBar Is Not Working Properly

Tags: wpf

I am trying to keep **ScrollViewr** to **datagrid** but its not scrolling when I am using **Up and Down Arrows**.But When I am trying to move ScrollBar with **mouse** its working fine. **Why ScrollBar is not moving when data moving Up and Down**.Please give your valuable Suggestions. Here is my code

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgsuggest" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
PreviewKeyDown="dgsuggest_PreviewKeyDown" SelectedIndex="0">
```

And my handler code is as follows

```
    private void dgsuggest_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {            
       if (e.Key==Key.Down)
        {
            if (dgsuggest.Items.Count - 1 > dgsuggest.SelectedIndex)
                dgsuggest.SelectedIndex++;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Up)
        {
            if (dgsuggest.SelectedIndex > 0)
                dgsuggest.SelectedIndex--;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: post the handler's code as well

Comment: @SamTheDev I have placed Handler Code please check

Comment: Have you debugged the problem? Put a breakpoint in the handler and step through the code when it is running to see what is actually happeneing... then come back here and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the DataGrid is not scrolling is because you are only changing the selection. If you want to change the items in view you can use [DataGrid.ScrollIntoView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc673083(v=vs.110).aspx) after changing the selection. Calling this method and providing the newly selected object will move your ScrollBar when the view is adjusted.

```
private void dgsuggest_PreviewKeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e )
    {
        var datagrid = sender as DataGrid;
        if( datagrid == null ) return;

        if( e.Key == Key.Down )
        {
            if( datagrid.Items.Count - 1 > datagrid.SelectedIndex )
                datagrid.SelectedIndex++;

            datagrid.ScrollIntoView( datagrid.SelectedItem );

            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if( e.Key == Key.Up )
        {
            if( datagrid.SelectedIndex > 0 )
                datagrid.SelectedIndex--;

            datagrid.ScrollIntoView( datagrid.SelectedItem );

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

As a note the reason the normal Key Up and Down events are not functioning like expected is because of your handler. Marking the event as handled is causing it not to scroll. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish by changing the selected index in code, but the default functionality of the DataGrid will already increment/decrement your selected index for key up and down events. Removing the handler entirely will give you the same result as the code I have provided.

Comment: Thank you so much. you gave me Exact Solution